# git on linux subsystem for windows not working

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having trouble with git with Bash on windows 10. I have the Microsoft store Ubuntu app installed and I'm using it to develop some go code.

When I try to push committed changes to my private github repo, git hangs on

```
ssh git@github.com git-receive-pack <myrepo>
```

Eventually it would tell me that remote end hung up. Sometimes the message is that I don't have permissions/repo might not exist. Funny thing, it pushed once, yesterday evening after 2 minutes of hanging. And then another 50tries timed out/died/hung

A clone action:

```
macieks@DESKTOP-6O1RI8O:~/playground$ git clone 
git@github.com:hashicorp/consul.git
Cloning into 'consul'...
remote: Counting objects: 47456, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Connection reset by 192.30.253.113 port 2254 MiB | 1.86 MiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

At the same time I can authenticate:

```
macieks@DESKTOP-6O1RI8O:~/playground$ ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi strzelecki-maciek! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not 
provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

Changing remote form ssh to https did not help. Tried disabling all windows firewalls/defenders. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you trying to ssh to github? You should be using the `git` command.

Comment: Is it possible that you misconfigured your remote? Try setting it again: $ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git

Comment: `Connection reset by 192.30.253.113 port 22` Is the problem persistent? If you attempt to pull from 192.30.253.112 instead, does it also break ? Remote looks to be fine (@SubChord) and using SSH is the correct way to test if your account details work (@Flimzy)

Comment: I showed u the ssh command to prove that my ssh key is set correctly and i am able to connect and authenticate at github. This isjust a test. It has no other use.

I reset the remotes several times to check for typos/errors. Whether its https or ssh it does not make any difference.

I am not able to clone new repo (as pasted the hashicorp/consul example) or git pull either.

Answer (score 0):

So, there was an uplink problem. The internet provider resolved it the next day. It was slightly confusing as no other internet-using-device/software was minding this problem at all, git was the only thing affected. :-)